# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'

Tags: python, kivy

i have a error: from kivy.app import App
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'

I have installed kivy by pip.

all kivy elements are here.

```
pip list
Package                   Version
------------------------- ----------
altgraph                  0.17.3
certifi                   2023.7.22
charset-normalizer        3.2.0
distlib                   0.3.7
docutils                  0.20.1
filelock                  3.12.4
idna                      3.4
Kivy                      2.3.0.dev0
kivy-deps.angle           0.3.3
kivy-deps.glew            0.3.1
kivy-deps.sdl2            0.6.0
Kivy-examples             2.3.0.dev0
Kivy-Garden               0.1.5


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import button  

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return button(text='hello world')

TestApp.run()
```

I tried many solutions to this problem, but none of them helped, most people say just write to terminal pip install kivy